# swing get visible frames

Tags: java, swing

How can I find all visible frames/dialogs in program? I could subclass JFrame/JDialog classes to update the list of currently visible windows, but if there is a built-in solution for this that would be much better

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
List<Window> visibleWindows = new ArrayList<Window>();
for(Window w: Window.getWindows()){
    if(w.isShowing()){
        visibleWindows.add(w);
    }
}
```

References:

1. [`getWindows()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows%28%29)
2. [`isShowing()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isShowing%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [Moonbeam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726208/swing-get-visible-frames/6726343#6726343). additionally you can say:

`Toolikit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener()`

... and subscribe to all window related events. In this case you will get information that window is created immediatly.