# java how to get top level component

Tags: java, swing, awt

I mean in 'mouse point of view'. Something with highest Z-order.
Stuck on JPopupMenu that could not be even part of 'parent-child' relations.

Thanks.

---

In tests I need to verify that a JPopupMenu component appeared on the screen. I don't have any specific additional attributes of that JPopuMenu to find all JPopupMenus by that predicate and check if any of them is visible. I would like to get all visible top level components and verify one of them is of class JPopupMenu.

Comment: please post here code in the http://sscce.org/ form, demonstraded your requirent(s)

Comment: beware: JPopupMenus are not necessarily shown in a top level component - if they are lightweight, they are added to the layeredPane of the owner's top-level parent rootpane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm also not clear on the question, but if you want the highest parent of some Component, there is   `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component);`

If you want a list of all the visible windows, see an earlier Stackoverflow question, [swing get visible frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726208/swing-get-visible-frames)

EDIT ADDED

Then look into @mKorbel suggestion of getComponentZOrder.  But JPopupMenus can be weird on their parentage.

Rereading your question, you might want to get all the top-level Windows and call getComponentPopupMenu() to check for a match.

Or, if you have an x,y location, the best solution would be to call findComponentAt(x,y).  From the javadocs:

"Locates the visible child component that contains the specified position. The top-most child component is returned in the case where there is overlap in the components. If the containing child component is a Container, this method will continue searching for the deepest nested child component. Components which are not visible are ignored during the search."

Comment: I need opposite to SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component); in 'visibility point of view'. I need child with highest z-order

Comment: +1,  @Mykhaylo Adamovych again post a SSCCEE, because everything shoud or should'd be correct and right way, why we need to ask you for provide good ad correct suggetion for you......

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on your question, but I think that [`getComponentZOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component%29) would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if a JPopupMenu is considered a child of a JFrame.

But if it is then you should be able to use Darryl's [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class to find them.